# Como eliminar class específica após retorno de deleção em banco

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando eliminar uma `class` após deleção em banco, no script que tinha eu deletava `li` com esse linha aqui no meu código:

```
$el.parents('li').remove();
```

Mas a minha necessidade é outra, ao retornar de uma deleção preciso eliminar a `class` que tem a imagem exibida para o cliente, mas não tenho conhecimento em `JQuery` para realizar o que preciso, mesmo pesquisando.

```
<div class="masonry-gallery columns-5 clearfix">
<a class="image-hover lightbox" href="<?php echo $ImagemArquivo->Caminho; ?>" data-plugin-options='{"type":"image"}'>
    <span class="image-hover-icon image-hover-dark">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
    </span>
    <img src="<?php echo $ImagemArquivo->Caminho; ?>" alt="...">                            
</a>
<button name="btnExcluir" idcooperadoarquivo="<?php echo $ImagemArquivo->IdCooperadoArquivo; ?>" cpf="<?php echo $ImagemArquivo->CPF; ?>" class="btn" type="button" >Excluir</button><br />
    <div class="alert alert-warning margin-bottom-30">
        Nenhum arquivo para exibição.
    </div>
```

O que tentei fazer:

```
function(response){                                     
if (response.codigo == "0") {                               
        $("#msgResult").html('×Close' + response.mensagem  + '');   
            // OCULTANDO A MENSAGEM DE ERRO E REDIRECIONANDO
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert").fadeTo(300, 0).slideUp(300, function(){
                    $(this).remove();   
                    window.location.href = "iGaleria.php"; 
                });
            }, 3000);                                       
    }                                       
}); 
// TENTEI REMOVER A CLASS DESSA FORMA
$(this).closest(".masonry-gallery").remove();
```

Comment: Já tentou usar removeClass? $("div").removeClass("masonry-gallery");

Comment: Você esta tentando remover a classe de um elemento ou os elementos que contenham a classe? Se o objetivo é remover o elemento, o problema pode estar no `this` da linha `$(this).closest(".masonry-gallery").remove();`, para que essa linha funcione `this` previsa ser um elemento contido dentro de `masonry-gallery`